# How to send keydown event to inactive window in C++?

Tags: c++, sendmessage, postmessage

[C++] How to send keydown event to inactive window?

TAB key works fine. But I'm having trouble with other keys such as "Z". Been googling this for a while but haven't found a solution so far.

Virtual key 0x5A should be the correct for letter Z.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

LPCSTR Target_window_Name = "Untitled - Notepad"; //<- Has to match window name
HWND hWindowHandle = FindWindow(NULL,Target_window_Name);

int main()
{
   //send TAB DOWN - WORKS FINE
   SendMessage(hWindowHandle,WM_KEYDOWN,0x09,0);
   //send TAB DOWN
   SendMessage(hWindowHandle,WM_KEYUP,0x09,0);

   //send Z DOWN - NOT WORKING
   SendMessage(hWindowHandle,WM_KEYDOWN,0x5A,0);
   //send Z UP
   SendMessage(hWindowHandle,WM_KEYUP,0x5A,0);

   return(0);
}
```

PS Keydown and Up events are required for what I'm trying to do.
Tried searching from several places, but I haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: Why not `PostMessage(hWindowHandle, WM_CHAR, 0x5A, 0);` ?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I would lose the functionality of keydown and keyup events.

Comment: Can you try `SendMessage(hWindowHandle,WM_KEYUP,VK_Z,0);` just to be sure?

Comment: Tried it now. MinGW could not compile the code:"1.cpp:24:39: error: 'VK_Z' was not declared in this scope" I declared a new value as "DWORD VK_Z = 0x5A;" which would remove the error. The button press didn't work with Z. Again it worked with Tab key when i changed the code to 0x09.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Use Spy++ and hook messages received by Notepad when you press `Z` key. That way you can simulate/emulate EXACTLY same thing, so it will look like exactly as user pressed `Z` key. 
Also you need to find `Edit` class in Notepad to send messages.
So I did this, I ran Spy++, hooked messages, and wrote the same thing. Now it works:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



int main()
{
    LPCSTR Target_window_Name = "Untitled - Notepad"; //<- Has to match window name
    HWND hWindowHandle = FindWindow(NULL,Target_window_Name);
    HWND EditClass = FindWindowEx(hWindowHandle, NULL, "Edit", NULL);

    SendMessage(EditClass,WM_KEYDOWN,0x5A,0x002C0001);
    SendMessage(EditClass,WM_CHAR,0x7A,0x002C0001);
    SendMessage(EditClass,WM_KEYUP,0x5A,0xC02C0001);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Now it works. Too bad I have to grab so many new values of lparam and wparam to y struct now. Atleast it works.                                       Thank you!

Comment: No problem. That's the way Win API works. You can accept the answer and close the question.