# Map missing chars on italian keyboards

Tags: windows, winapi, keyboard

I would like map a chars that doesn't exists on my keyboard layout is it possible?

My keyboard layout is [italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Italian_Keyboard_layout.svg) and the the chars is ~ and `
I would like remap when I press AltGr (VK_RMENU) + VK_OEM_4 or VK_OEM_6.

But this chars aren't in [Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) list, so I think I coud't use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) for remapping...

For others chars *SendInput* works

Comment: How are they missing? I am looking at standard Italian layouts and these characters are there.

Comment: This chars aren't on my keyboard

Answer (score 0):

> But this chars aren't in Virtual-Key Codes list, so I think I coud't
>   use SendInput for remapping...

The ~ and ` **are** in the [Virtual-Key Codes list](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes). It is **VK_OEM_3 (0xC0)**.

[image]

You can use SendInput enter ~ and ` like this:

```
UINT result = 0;
DWORD errCode = 0;

tagINPUT inputArray[2] = {};
tagKEYBDINPUT keyboardInput[2] = {};

keyboardInput[1].wVk = 0xC0; // Virtual-Key code for the '`~' key.
keyboardInput[1].wScan = 0x29; // Scan code for the '`~' key.

inputArray[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
inputArray[1].ki = keyboardInput[1];


keyboardInput[0].wVk = 0x10; // Virtual-Key code for the 'shift' key.
keyboardInput[0].wScan = 0x2A; // Scan code for the 'shift' key.

inputArray[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
inputArray[0].ki = keyboardInput[0];

// Enter '~' (shift + '`~' key)
result = SendInput(2, inputArray, sizeof(tagINPUT));
errCode = GetLastError();

// Enter '`'
result = SendInput(1, &inputArray[1], sizeof(tagINPUT));
errCode = GetLastError();
```

If you want to enter these two chars the SendMessage also can do this ([similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223668/how-do-you-send-keystrokes-to-an-inactive-window/54231361#54231361)):

```
LPCWSTR Target_window_Name = TEXT("Untitled - Notepad"); //<- Has to match window name
HWND hWindowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, Target_window_Name);
HWND EditClass = FindWindowEx(hWindowHandle, NULL, L"Edit", NULL);


SendMessage(EditClass, WM_KEYDOWN, 0xC0, 0x002C0001); //VK_OEM_3 0xC0
SendMessage(EditClass, WM_CHAR, 0x7E, 0x002C0001); //~
SendMessage(EditClass, WM_KEYUP, 0xC0, 0xC02C0001);

SendMessage(EditClass, WM_KEYDOWN, 0xC0, 0x002C0001); //VK_OEM_3 0xC0
SendMessage(EditClass, WM_CHAR, 0x60, 0x002C0001); //`
SendMessage(EditClass, WM_KEYUP, 0xC0, 0xC02C0001);
```

References: "[SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)" "[SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage)"

For scan code you can search "Keyboard Scan Code Specification - Microsoft".