# Press and release key to background window

Tags: java, windows, jna, user32

I'm trying to write a program that **holds button for a few seconds and releases it to specific HWND that don't have focus**.

I found this [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223668/how-do-you-send-keystrokes-to-an-inactive-window):

```
public static void pressKey(String window, long wparam, long lparam) {
    WinDef.HWND hWindowHandle = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null, window);
    WinDef.HWND editClass = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindowEx(hWindowHandle, null, "Edit", null);
    
    User32.INSTANCE.SendMessage(editClass, WM_KEYDOWN, new WPARAM(wparam), new LPARAM(lparam));
    User32.INSTANCE.SendMessage(editClass, WM_CHAR, new WPARAM(wparam), new LPARAM(lparam));
    User32.INSTANCE.SendMessage(editClass, WM_KEYUP, new WPARAM(wparam), new LPARAM(lparam));
}
```

But that method types key, not presses and releases it after a few seconds. I tried removing line that contains `WM_CHAR` and `WM_KEYUP`, but it didn't work.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). That said, is there a reason you aren't using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32)?

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks